# Evaluate $PV \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1-e^{iax}}{x^2}dx. a>0$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration, residue-calculus, cauchy-principal-value

Evaluate $PV \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1-e^{iax}}{x^2}dx.  a>0$ using residues.

So I have a theory how to calculate $PV \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x)e^{iax}dx$ a>0, but I don’t know how to transform my integral to this form.

Comment: Integrating by part first,
$$I=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1-e^{iax}}{x^2}dx=-\frac{1-e^{iax}}{x}\bigg|_{-\infty}^\infty-ia\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac {e^{iax}}{x}dx$$
Only $\sin ax$ contributes (the even part of the integrand contributes)
$$I=-ia\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac {\sin ax}{x}dx$$

Comment: Two alternative methods: (i) The real part is $\int_{\Bbb R}\frac{2\sin^2\frac{ax}{2}dx}{x^2}$. (ii) A semicircular contour passes through the integrand's first-order pole $z=0$, so it "half-counts" in the residue theorem (you can make this more rigorous with a small semicircular arc oriented to either include or exclude the pole within the full contour).

Comment: @Svyatoslav If I’m not mistaken, i should be before sin(ax)

Comment: $e^{iax} = cos ax + i sin ax$

Comment: Yes, you are right. I lost $i$. My apology

Comment: @Svyatoslav It s hard to see, why $\frac{1 - e^{iax}}{x}$ equals 0?(x = +-inf)

Comment: because $1-e^{iax}$ is limited, and $\frac{1}{x}\to 0$ at $x\to \pm\infty$

Comment: I somehow forgot about the i in the power of the e, thank you:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\begin{align}I&=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1-e^{iax}}{x^2}dx\\&=-\frac{1-e^{iax}}{x}\bigg|_{-\infty}^\infty-ia\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac {e^{iax}}{
x}dx\\&= -ia\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac {e^{iax}}{x}dx\\&= -ia\times\pi i\operatorname{Res}_{z=0} 
\frac{e^{iaz}}{z}\\& = -ia\times\pi i e^{iaz} \bigg|_{z=0}\\& = \pi a\end{align}$$

Comment: It may be worth explaining why there's a $\pi i$ factor. (My comment under the OP hints at the reason.)

Comment: @J.G. So we can prove a special lemma (at university we called them "about semi-residue"), where "The semicircular contour passes through the first order pole of the integrand =0" :)

Comment: It's a shame people don't seem to have given it a standard name. I advise third parties interested in a proof to look at theorems 9.13 & 9.14 [here](https://math.mit.edu/~jorloff/18.04/notes/topic9.pdf).

Comment: @J.G.Thanks for sharing, I'm very interested. In Russia we call it the «semi-residue lemma» :)